# Using custom Webfonts on Teachable

Tags: cross-domain, webfonts

I am trying to use a custom font on my client's course marketing page on Teachable.com. Right now the course is not currently live, so unfortunately I can't share a link to preview.

I am trying to follow the Google Webfonts pattern of attributes in the link tag:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://tablocreative.com/roo/webfonts.css" crossorigin>
```

I am hosting this webfont and the respective font files on a different hosting provider (standard Apache hosting). When I view the source of my page, I can see that file is being referenced - no 404 errors or access origin errors in the console.

This is the CSS:

```
html, body, main, div, p { font-family: 'Avenir LT Pro'; }
```

I can see in the inspector that declaration is being applied, no other font-family is set or overriding this. But the webfont will not load.

Any insights or ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the codepen on the readme of this repo.
It has a working example:

https://github.com/adriano-tirloni/google-fonts-css2

Comment: Thanks your your response! Are you referring to this Codepen? https://codepen.io/adrianotirloni/pen/ExEWbdd
I was easily able to get Google Fonts and Adobe Fonts working on Teachable. I am not able to get custom web fonts on my own hosting to work.